# Create multiple databases dynamically in Microsoft Azure

Tags: database, azure

I am a newbie in Microsoft Azure platform. I want to create multiple databases dynamically (We are developing multi-tenant model. So, Each organization should have their own database. Whenever an organization is registered with our system, we need to create a new database dynamically). Please provide some insights on this.

Answer (score 1):

By using [Azure Resource Manager Templates](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/resource-group-overview/) you can reliably deploy the whole infrastructure required by each organisation. So if they need a webserver, database and middleware servers, you can define the whole thing in a template and reliably deploy that for every client.

(from the above link)

- You can deploy, manage, and monitor all of the resources for your solution as a group, rather than handling these resources individually.
- You can repeatedly deploy your solution throughout the development lifecycle and have confidence your resources are deployed in a consistent state.
- You can use declarative templates to define your deployment.
- You can define the dependencies between resources so they are deployed in the correct order.
- You can apply access control to all services in your resource group because Role-Based Access Control (RBAC) is natively integrated into the management platform.
- You can apply tags to resources to logically organize all of the resources in your subscription.
- You can clarify billing for your organization by viewing the rolled-up costs for the entire group or for a group of resources sharing the same tag.

The link above has a lot of resources for learning how to use templates as well as the syntax and usage.

There are a large number of templates at the Azure ARM Template [Github page](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates) and even some [pre-existing](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-web-app-sql-database) templates to get you  [started](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/sql-server-2014-alwayson-dsc) deploying SQL Server to Azure (there's also [mysql](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/mysql-replication) and [postgress](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/postgresql-on-ubuntu) if you prefer)

Plus many others that you can work through to get accustomed to how they work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the AZURE SQL Database REST API to do so, its as simple as sending a PUT Request to a URL https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group-name}/providers/microsoft.sql/servers/{server-name}/databases/{database-name}?api-version={api-version}

Check out these links for more details

1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163571.aspx
2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163685.aspx